# Stored procedure strange error when called through php

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I have been coding a registration page(login system) in php and mysql for a website. I'm using two stored procedures for the same. First stored procedure checks wether the email address already exists in database.Second one inserts the user supplied data into mysql database. User has EXECUTE permission on both the procedures.When is execute them individually from php script they work fine. But when i use them together in script second Stored procedure(insert) not working.

**Stored procedure 1.**

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE reg_check_email(email VARCHAR(80))
BEGIN
SET @email = email;
SET @sql = 'SELECT email FROM user_account WHERE user_account.email=?';
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt USING @email;
END$$
DELIMITER;
```

**Stored procedure 2**

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE reg_insert_into_db(fname VARCHAR(40), lname VARCHAR(40), email      VARCHAR(80), pass VARBINARY(32), licenseno VARCHAR(80), mobileno VARCHAR(10))
BEGIN
SET @fname = fname, @lname = lname, @email = email, @pass = pass, @licenseno =    licenseno, @mobileno = mobileno;
SET @sql = 'INSERT INTO user_account(email,pass,last_name,license_no,phone_no)    VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)';
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt USING @email,@pass,@lname,@licenseno,@mobileno;
END$$
DELIMITER;
```

When i test these from php sample script insert is not working , but first stored procedure(reg_check_email()) is working. If i comment off first one(reg_check_email), second stored procedure(reg_insert_into_db) is working fine.

```
 <?php
 require("/wamp/mysql.inc.php");
 $r = mysqli_query($dbc,"CALL reg_check_email('ravi@gmail.com')");
 $rows = mysqli_num_rows($r);
 if($rows == 0) {
     $r = mysqli_query($dbc,"CALL   reg_insert_into_db('a','b','ravi@gmail.com','c','d','e')");
     }
 ?>
```

i'm unable to figure out the mistake.

Thanks in advance,
ravi.

Comment: what is the error message you are getting?

Comment: Did you check what $rows is returning by doing a echo?

Comment: So what is it returning?

Comment: @somnath since my database table is empty , $rows is returning 0. I also kept an echo inside if conditional.Even it is working.

Comment: Some unrelated tips: A valid email address can be up to 253 characters long. You should make the email address a unique index and just try to insert rather than select then insert. However, if you want to keep doing it your way, you should use SELECT FOR UPDATE and transactions (or LOCK TABLES with MyISAM) to avoid getting duplicate inserts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the similar kind of issues, while executing stored procedures and queries using php script.

You should try [mysqli_multi_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) for executing your SPs.
After calling procedures. use **mysqli_free_result** to consume results.
You can refer [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7691010/getting-error-commands-out-of-sync-you-cant-run-the-command-now-while-execut) as well. Hope, it'll help you.