# MySQL "commands out of sync" appears when migrating to stored procedures

Tags: mysql

I have some working php/mysql which I am now migrating to stored procedures.

As soon as any stored procedure is called, subsequent CALLs and SELECTs fail with "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now".

Existing stored procedures which are not SELECTs work fine.

```
function db_all ($query)
{
    log_sql_read ($query);
    $result = mysql_query ($query, db_connection ());

    if (!$result)
    {
        log_sql_error ($query);
        return Array ();
    }

    $rows = Array ();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc ($result))
        array_push ($rows, $row);

    mysql_free_result ($result);

    return $rows;
}

db_all ("SELECT 1 as `test`");
db_all ("SELECT 2 as `test`");
db_all ("CALL `$db`.`select_info`($id);"); // RETURNS CORRECT DATA
db_all ("CALL `$db`.`select_info`($id);"); // ERROR HERE
db_all ("SELECT 5 as `test`");             // ERROR HERE
```

This error is explained elsewhere as a result of not calling `mysql_free_result`, but I **do** call this. So what's wrong?

I'm seeing some solutions which refer to mysqli. I need a *non-mysqli* solution for now.

Comment: Please would you post the stored procedure. It looks like you're doing something wrong there.

Comment: It's a bit complicated but the problem persists with trivial stored procedures.

Comment: @spraff The problem is that SP returns two resultsets and you need to consume them both before making another call. See updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is when executed, a stored procedure will give you two resultsets back. One with the actual resultset and another with the status of the executing. And you need to consume both before making another call that returns result set.

In `mysqli_*` you can utilize `mysqli_multi_query`, `mysqli_store_result`, `mysqli_next_result` to achieve that. You can see how to do that in `mysqli`[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7691133/1920232).

In your case with `mysql_*` you can just close the connection after you done fetching results.

```php
function db_all ($query)
{
    $link = db_connection();     //Open connection

    log_sql_read ($query);
    $result = mysql_query ($query, $link);

    if (!$result)
    {
        log_sql_error ($query);
        return Array ();
    }

    $rows = Array ();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc ($result))
        array_push ($rows, $row);

    mysql_free_result ($result);
    mysql_close($link);          //Close the connection
    return $rows;
}
```