# Codeigniter: how to call multiple model function in single controller function in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am new to coidigniter.

If I am calling single model method from controller function then its working fine.

If I amt try to call more than one model function from single model, through single controller function, then  I get

> Fetal Error:Call to a member function result() on Boolean

my code look like this

controller.php

```
public function get_details(){

   $this->my_model->get_company();  //first call

   $this->my_model->get_employee();  //second call

}
```

my_model.php

```
public function get_company(){

 $qry="CALL get_company_details";

 $result=$this->db->query($qry);

 foreach($result->result() as $row){

   $data[]=$row;

 }

return $data;

}


public function get_employee(){

 $qry="CALL get_employee_details";

 $result=$this->db->query($qry);

 foreach($result->result() as $row){

   $data[]=$row;

 }

return $data; 

}
```

Can I call like that.
Please help me...

Comment: $this->load->model('Model_name'); and $this->Model_name->function();

Comment: Can you please give the quires you run by $this->db->query($qry);

Comment: I have loaded through in 'public function _construct(){}

Comment: Please print your query then copy and to phpmyadmin and check its working or not

Comment: SELECT * FROM company and SELECT * FROM employee

Comment: Fetal Error:Call to a member function result() on Boolean its actually database error , so please check quires and database connection

Comment: Query is working fine. only i am getting when i am calling both function. if am calling single(first/second call) function then i am not getting any error

Comment: $data=array(); 

if ($result->num_rows() > 0)
{
foreach($result->result() as $row){

   $data[]=$row;

 }
}

Comment: I changed then i am getting "Fetal Error:Call to a member function num_rows()"

Comment: I think you should check db connection in application/config/database.php again

Comment: using stored procedure for such a small task like `select * from table` is **overkill**.

Comment: When i set $db['default']['db_debug']=TRUE; Then i got 'Command out of sync; you canot run this command now'.. try to find solution  based on this error. still i dint reach.

Comment: Thank you All. Finally i got IT, I followed this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7691010/getting-error-commands-out-of-sync-you-cant-run-the-command-now-while-execut

Answer (score 0):

Simple typo:

Change

```
function get_company(){
```

to

```
function get_employee(){
```

You have defined same function twice.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your database connection is ok in application/config/database.php

```
$data = array();

    $qry="SELECT * FROM . . . . ."; // your query 

    $result=$this->db->query($qry);
    if($result->num_rows() > 0){
     foreach($result->result() as $row){

       $data[]=$row;

     }
    }


    return $data;
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
$result=$this->db->query($qry);
 foreach($result->result() as $row){
   $data[]=$row;
 }
return $data;
```

to

```
return $result->result_array();
```

That should solve your problem. You can check [result_array()](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html) section of CodeIgniter documentation.